# Amazon EC2: why do some instances have no option for networking or ip association

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

HI I notice that on some spot instances I get this weird issue whereby the instance does not have any network options nor can I associate an IP with it.  I checked and its all running from the same data centers (us-west-1a) sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.  Has anyone else experience this or have an idea what I can do?  thanks. Below is an screenshot. [image]

Comment: Is this instance in a VPC, or is it in EC2-Classic?  I don't suspect that none of these options is available to classic machines, or at least not while running.

Comment: Did you provision these instances manually or are they provisioned by AWS through e.g. EMR?

Comment: Hi, @Michael-sqlbot hmm that is good point; when I check the instances that work they all have VPC id's while this one does not.  I see the option now.  thank you.   I think this is the solution.

Comment: Yes, I just checked and I had to check VPC as the network option.  Great. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Michael-sqlbot in comment above the issue was when creating a spot instance there is an option under network to either select ecs-classic or VPC.  A bit of confusion is that only certain ecs type of an option to chose while some just default to VPC.  This was why sometimes some of spinups has network options like elastic IP, etc.  Anyways, by manually chosing VPC I'm now able to configure the network now.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have more than one instance selected. In that case some of them (including Networking and Instance Settings) are greyed out.

Select just one instance and try.

Comment: Yes I tried this and its still grey.  The other instance I have is fine though.